# Initial support for a Xamarin beginner

Tags: c#, google-maps, menu, xamarin.forms

I'm a C#, Deplhi, Clipper and Pascal (among others) developer. I met Xamarin, and it was love at first sight, and I'm trying to learn with development challenges of serious applications.
However, please, I need a kick of something I want to make: attached to this thread, you can see an imagen with a prototype of a menu for my application. The problem is I dont know what controls can I use to make it possible. Currently, I'm not using XAML. Only C#, with controls created in the code and all has gone well.

What do you think? What controls can make the appearance in the picture?

Thanks in advance.

Gustavo

[app prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mHUb.png)

Comment: Please, how I can check both answers from @MarioGalvan and @Jason? Both answers are direct, technical and extremely valuable to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple app, Xamarin has very simple examples of the layouts you might need, for example for Navigation you can use:

A main navigation page

http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage/

And Content Pages for the rest of the flow:

http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage/

For the map you can use:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/

And for the ListView or list of buttons you can use a list view within a StackLayout with custom cells:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/controls/views/

This documentation is for Xamarin.Forms and will run on windows phone, iOS and Android.

There are also a lot of example apps which you can dig in if you are struggling with the code or architecture like this ones:

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/tag/Xamarin.Forms/

Comment: Excelent, Mario. Great help!

Answer (score 2):

Use a StackLayout containing a MapView and a ListView.  Use a ViewCell for your ListView, containing a horizontal ListView that in turn contains Buttons, Labels, and Images.

Comment: Accurate and effective response, Jason. Thank you!